# If two sets only differ by a set of measure 0, and one of them is measurable, then the other is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

First, does it mean that their symmetric difference is a set of measure 0?

Second, if so, how do I prove this assertion? My thought is that I can show that their outer measure is equal. However, to show the other set is measurable following the definition, I should find an open set for every $\epsilon > 0$, can anyone give me some hint on this?

Comment: What do you mean by differ ?

Comment: That is my confusion also, since this is from Stein's book.

Comment: Did you really read and understand my answer within just one minute?

Comment: Yes, sure. I was in the wrong direction before, your answer is quite easy to understand also. @user21820

Comment: That's nice to hear, thank you. It's just that it's the first time my answer gets accepted in such a short time, so I was surprised. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes "set difference" refers to "symmetric difference". But how you prove it depends on what your **definitions** (such as of "measure") are and what **theorems** you already have. Probably you have enough prior theorems to carry out the following proof:
$
\def\diff{\mathbin{Δ}}
\def\less{\smallsetminus}
$

$A \diff B = ( A \less B ) \cup ( B \less A )$.

If $| A \diff B | = 0$ and $A$ is measurable:

$| A \less B | = 0$ and $| B \less A | = 0$.

Thus $A \cap B = A \less ( A \less B )$ is measurable.

And $B = ( A \cap B ) \cup ( B \less A )$ is measurable.